# Neo4j Springboot SpringData restful example not complete without relationship entity

Tags: rest, spring-boot, neo4j, client, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am using the springio accessing-neo4j-data-rest example which has the relationship as part of the Person class and really doesn't show the advantage of Neo4j.  I tried creating a Family relationship entity, but can't create a relationship using a restful service with Springboot and port 8080.

My service works and creates the relationship using http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/67/relationships

Shouldn't I be able to do this (where 66 and 67 are existing Person entities):

POST to http://localhost:8080/people/67/family

```
{
  "to" : "http://localhost:8080/people/66",
  "type" : "RELATED_TO"
}
```

I get the error:
{
  "timestamp": 1486948326367,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/people/67/family"
}

### Person.java

```
package hello;


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

@NodeEntity
public class Person {

    @GraphId public Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Relationship(type = Family.TYPE, direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    private Set<Family> family = new HashSet<Family>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Set<Family> getFamily() {
        return family;
    }

    public void addFamily(Family f) {
        family.add(f);
    }

    public void addFamily(Person target, String  association) {
        this.family.add(new Family(this, target, association));
    }

    public void addFamily(Person target) {
        this.family.add(new Family(this, target));
    }

}
```

### Family.java

```
package hello;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.EndNode;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Property;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.RelationshipEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.StartNode;

@RelationshipEntity(type = Family.TYPE)
public class Family {

    public static final String TYPE = "RELATED_TO";

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Property
    private String association;

    @StartNode
    private Person p1;

    @EndNode
    private Person p2;

    public Family() {
    }

    public Family(Person first, Person second) {
        this.p1 = first;
        this.p2 = second;
    }

    public Family(Person first, Person second, String assoc) {
        this.p1 = first;
        this.p2 = second;
        association = assoc;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Person getFirst() {
        return p1;
    }

    public Person getSecond() {
        return p2;
    }

    public String getAssociation() {
        return association;
    }

    public void setAssociation(String association) {
        this.association = association;
    }
}
```

### PersonRepository.java

```
package hello;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;


@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);
    List<Person> findByFirstName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

### FamilyRepository .java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "family", path = "family") // what should go here????
public interface FamilyRepository extends GraphRepository<Family> {

//    //creates a get - need a post
//    @Query("MATCH (a:Traveler),(b:Traveler) WHERE a.lastName = {from} AND b.lastName = {to} CREATE (a)-[r:RELATED_TO]->(b) RETURN r")
//    void worksWith(@Param("to") String to);

}
```

Edited:2-19-2017 - Getting closer.  I needed a controller - something like this:

```
@RestController
public class FamilyController {
...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/people/{id}/family", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON, produces = APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    @ResponseBody
    Family addFamily(@RequestBody Family f, @PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
```

Comment: @frant.hartm Did you add a comment?  I'm just seeing "edited 7 hours ago".

Comment: Nope, I just fixed the tag (sdn -> spring-data-neo4j-4)

Comment: And I can GET the relationships using: http://localhost:8080/people/67/family

Comment: I had to add a controller and annotate the method and change the url to http://localhost:8080/people/67/addfamily because if I just used /family then I couldn't GET http://localhost:8080/people/67/family without adding a method in the controller.  And add JsonProperty to the fields that needed to come and go from JSON and add JsonIgnore to the set of families in Person to avoid an infinite loop.